# Passing data to sibling components with react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to pass a variable `username` from `sibling1` component to `sibling2` component and display it there.

Sibling1 component:

```
const sibling1 = ({ usernameData }) => {
   // I want to pass the username value I get from input to sibling2 component
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(""); 

  const handleChange = event => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Form.Input
        icon='user'
        iconPosition='left'
        label='Username'
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    <Button content='Login' onClick={handleClick} />
  )
}

export default sibling1;
```

Sibling2 component:

```
export default function sibling2() {
  return (
    <h1> Here is where i want to display it </h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is sibling2 called from sibling1? If so, you can just pass props. Or else you need to store in-app state and get from there.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel we don't know if he was downvoter ;) (btw wasn't me) I suspect some answerers do serial downvoting sometimes if they get a downvote which ain't healthy

Comment: @giorgim That's right, i thought about it after. But the advide is still valid. And i meant nothing bad by saying that, it's just unproductive

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You will need to handle your userName in the parent of your siblings. then you can just pass `setUsername` to your sibling1, and `userName` to your sibling2. When sibling1 use setUsername, it will update your parent state and re-render your sibling2 (Because the prop is edited).

Here what it looks like :

```
const App = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('Default username');
  return (
    <>
      <Sibling1 setUsername={setUsername} />
      <Sibling2 username={username} />
    </>
  )
}

const Sibling2 = ({username}) => {
  return <h1> Helo {username}</h1>;
}

const Sibling1 = ({setUsername}) => {
  return <button onClick={setUsername}>Set username</button>;
}
```

Comment: THIS!! Best explanaiton to such a "hard" problem for me. Thank you:)

Comment: You're welcome ;) remember that component based language are like trees, so if leaves need something, it's provided by the trunk most of the time ;)

Comment: I'm getting this warning: `Warning: Cannot update a component (`TagsListPage`) while rendering a different component (`TagsListTableBody`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `TagsListTableBody`, follow the stack trace as described`... It seems better to go with Context solution from @tswistak

Comment: @Kostanos Without any code it's impossible to help you. Your problem might come from your own code so I can only advice you to open a new question if you don't find a solution. Using a context is a solution especially when you have to share data across multiple level of your tree.

Comment: The code in this answer will trigger the re-render of entire parent with its children. I'm looking for solution which will not trigger the full re-render, but only those siblings who involved on it

Answer (score 14):

In parent of these two components create a context where you will store a value and value setter (the best would be from useState). So, it will look like this:

```
export const Context = React.createContext({ value: null, setValue: () => {} });

export const ParentComponent = () => {
 const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

 return (
  <Context.Provider value={{value, setValue}}>
   <Sibling1 />
   <Sibling2 />
  </Context.Provider>
 );
```

Then in siblings you are using it like this:

```
const Sibling1 = () => {
 const {setValue} = useContext(Context);

 const handleChange = event => {
  setValue(event.target.value);
 };
 // rest of code here
}

const Sibling2 = () => {
 const {value} = useContext(Context);

 return <h1>{value}</h1>;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, if you want to avoid the parent to be re-rendered each time value is changed

Answer (score 3):

**best way: React Context + hooks**

you can use React Context. take a look at this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-api-example-0ghhy

Comment: how to Passing data sibling to parent  component using context ?