# Getting useState is lagging when getting input's value from useRef()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks

When I'm using the `input`s  `ref={inputRef}`  and using `setState` the value of the `state` is always one step behind - meaning, it owns its previous `value`.

When I type any string inside the input field, in the first button's it will have an empty string,  only in the second button's click it will have that string I entered and will fire the `console.log('searchString', searchString);` TWICE!

I was adviced in my previous question, that instead of calling `onChange={(e) => onChangHandler(e)}` each time I press a letter in input field I can just take the whole value when clicking the button for `activeSearch()` **ONE** time only.

```js
function Header({ setingResults }) {
  const [productsObj, setObjs] = useState([]);
  const [searchString, setString] = useState('');
  const inputRef = useRef();


 // const onChangHandler = (e) => {
 //   setString(e.target.value);
 // };

  const activeSearch = () => {
    setString(inputRef.current.value);
    if (searchString.length > 0) {
      console.log('searchString', searchString);
      setingResults(searchString);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <header className='header-shop'>
        Welcome to Vitamins Store
        <br />
        <input
          placeholder='Search here'
          ref={inputRef}
          // value={searchString}
          // onChange={(e) => onChangHandler(e)}
        />
        <button onClick={activeSearch}>Search</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Header;
```

**Anybody knows here whats the probelm ?**

I'll be glad for some help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Like shown in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68248921/1218980), you no longer need `setString(inputRef.current.value);` when using an uncontrolled input and a callback prop. You could use a local variable `const searchString = inputRef.current.value;`

Answer (score 1):

Not useRef but useState is lagging.

```js
  const activeSearch = () => {
    setString(inputRef.current.value);
    // here searchString is old value
    if (searchString.length > 0) {
      console.log('searchString', searchString);
      setingResults(searchString);
    }
  };
```

Comment: You can console.log the `inputRef.current.value` then you can see that is not lagging. And `setString` is not running synchronously.

Comment: Yes it's ture thanks, do you know how to make the `setString `  synchronously ? and why it's lagging ?

Comment: You can read [this post](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-doesnt-react-update-thisstate-synchronously) for reason.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding you goal correctly, the preferred way to do this would be a bit more simple.

```js
function Header({ setResults }) {
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState('');
  const activeSearch = () => setResults(searchString);
  const searchChange = (e) => setSearchString(e.target.value);
  return (
    <div>
    <header className='header-shop'>
        Welcome to Vitamins Store
        <br />
        <input
        placeholder='Search here'
        value={searchString}
        onChange={searchChange}
        />
        <button onClick={activeSearch}>Search</button>
    </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Header;
```

Setting `value` and `onChange` on your input makes it a ["controlled input"](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), setting the value of `searchString` every time the input value is changed, and passing `activeSearch` to the `onClick` of your button simply calls your `setResults` prop with the current value of the input.

If all you need is to keep track of the input value, `ref`s are rarely needed.

Comment: An [uncontrolled input is a totally valid solution in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42522515/1218980). Both ways work, but in this case, managing an additional state is useless when we only care about the state when clicking a button.