# useState sending props only in the second onClick, with a string at the first onClick, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, use-state

When setting useState `const [searchString, setString] = useState([])`  with a string `setString("some string")` it will be sent it immediately and shown at the other component `<Home/>`,
**BUT** when I send an array it will be stated `settingResults(resultArray)` only after the second `onClick` here.
I tried `settingResults([...resultArray])`- its the same.

All functions checked with `console.log()`.

Header.jsx

```js
function Header({ settingResults }) {
  const [productsObj, setObjs] = useState([]);
  const [searchString, setString] = useState('');
  let resultArray = [];


  const onChangHandler = (e) => {
    setString(e.target.value);
  };

  const activeSearch = () => {
    if (searchString.length > 0) {
      resultArray = productsObj.filter((obj) =>
        obj.productName.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase())
      );
      if (resultArray.length !== 0) {

        settingResults(resultArray);
      }
    }
    resultArray = [];
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header className='header-shop'>
        Welcome to Vitamins Store
        <br />
        <input
          placeholder='Search here'
          value={searchString}
          onChange={(e) => onChangHandler(e)}
        />
        <button onClick={activeSearch}>Search</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.js

```js
function App() {
  const [searchString, setString] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Header settingResults={setString} />
      <Home searchResults={searchString} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Home.jsx

```js
function Home({ searchResults }) {
  const [itemSearchResults, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [viewResults, setViewResult] = useState(null);
  let itemsFound = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    setResults(searchResults);
    itemsFound = itemSearchResults.map((productObj) => {
      return (
        <div key={productObj.id}>
          {productObj.productName} <br />
          {productObj.price}
          <br />
          <img src={productObj.image} />
        </div>
      );
    });
    setViewResult(itemsFound);
  }, [searchResults]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home</h3>
      <h1>{viewResults}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Anyone know why `useState` won't work first time with an object-array ?**

Comment: I believe your ```resultArray``` be re-rendered every time you set a value with ```setString```. Maybe you can use ```useRef``` instead to prevent this to happening.

Comment: using `let resultArray` means the reference is always the same... you should probably store that in a state.

Comment: Can you post the `Home` code where the results get used? You should consider calling `setttingResults` even when the results or search are empty in order to clear past searches.

Comment: @edemaine As you asked `Home` is on !

Comment: @Noriller When doing that it will take 3 times(!!!) to onClick to send the array props.

Comment: There's also a couple working example of your code in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68248921/1218980) on your previous question, which shows exactly what to do to list the results. (see the interactive "Show code snippet" sections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code are these two lines:

```js
    setResults(searchResults);
    itemsFound = itemSearchResults...
```

Calling `setResults` does not immediately change `itemSearchResults`.  Instead, it queues a change to happen after the current render.  But this code won't get called again until `searchResults` changes again.

Why are you using `itemSearchResults` at all? It seems like you could just use `searchResults`, like the following minimal change: (but see below for better answers)

```js
function Home({ searchResults }) {
  const [viewResults, setViewResult] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const itemsFound = searchResults.map((productObj) => {
      return (
        <div key={productObj.id}>
          {productObj.productName} <br />
          {productObj.price}
          <br />
          <img src={productObj.image} />
        </div>
      );
    });
    setViewResult(itemsFound);
  }, [searchResults]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home</h3>
      <h1>{viewResults}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code would also be better written with `useMemo`:

```js
function Home({ searchResults }) {
  const viewResults = useMemo(() => {
    return searchResults.map((productObj) => {
      return (
        <div key={productObj.id}>
          {productObj.productName} <br />
          {productObj.price}
          <br />
          <img src={productObj.image} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }, [searchResults]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home</h3>
      <h1>{viewResults}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, it's dangerous to memoize in this way, and you'd be better off directly rendering like so:

```js
function Home({ searchResults }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home</h3>
      <h1>
        {searchResults.map((productObj) =>
          <div key={productObj.id}>
            {productObj.productName} <br />
            {productObj.price}
            <br />
            <img src={productObj.image} />
          </div>
        )}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

// This will guarantee re-rendering only when the props change.
Memo = React.memo(Memo);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it's now working, I am confused with the `useState` , It happened in the `Header` component but wasn't read at the `Home` component.  Now you explained me why. I think with setState() in class based component its working immediately (idk really) becasue I use Hooks, think they are much more better. Now going to read about `useMemo`.

Comment: Do not memoize JSX, just render it.

Comment: I'm trying to understand `useMemo`,  if same search result are being send in props to `Home` so `useMemo` will prevent rendering the DOM ?   *How can I check it* ?     In ***reactjs.org*** -      "useMemo will only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies has changed" - What does this mean ?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks for showing here, Can you explain better "Do not memoize JSX" ? I'm reading a-lot but didn't figure it out.

Comment: @Sunny rendered elements (JSX) should only be placed inside the render phase. In the case of memoized elements, older elements that were rendered in a previous phase will be used for the current render phase, which is similar to rendering outside the render phase. The lifecycle of these elements could be messed up, there's a lot of potential problems with this approach, which would be an anti-pattern in React.

Comment: Also, there's [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) which is different than `useMemo`, and would be fine to use on this component, though probably unnecessary.

Comment: This answer is also suggesting to [put elements inside the state, which is another anti-pattern in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875226/1218980). Here's [how to render a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41374572/1218980).